# rails 3 create sets values to bill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So after a merge, my RoR 3 project no longer does 'creates' correctly. Default attributes get set correctly, but not the ones I pass in:

```
1.9.3-p125 :020 > f=Ifilter.create(:name => "test2", :regex => "()" )
SQL (101.5ms)  INSERT INTO "ifilters" ("created_at", "name", "regex", "updated_at") VALUES    (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 10 Mar 2012 03:36:24 UTC +00:00], ["name", nil], ["regex", nil], ["updated_at", Sat, 10 Mar 2012 03:36:24 UTC +00:00]]

=> #<Ifilter id: 2, name: nil, regex: nil, created_at: "2012-03-10 03:36:24", updated_at: "2012-03-10 03:36:24">
```

However, save still works:

```
1.9.3-p125 :021 > f=Ifilter.new
 => #<Ifilter id: nil, name: nil, regex: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3-p125 :022 > f.name = "test"
 => "test" 
1.9.3-p125 :023 > f.regex = "()"
 => "()" 
1.9.3-p125 :024 > f.save
  SQL (4.8ms)  INSERT INTO "ifilters" ("created_at", "name", "regex", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 10 Mar 2012 04:13:10 UTC +00:00], ["name", "test"], ["regex", "()"], ["updated_at", Sat, 10 Mar 2012 04:13:10 UTC +00:00]]
 => true
```

What's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining the model?

Comment: Just completely standard - rails generate scaffold ifilter name:string regex:string . Nothing go merged into ifilter, but stuff in the framework may have been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may have `attr_accessible` on your model. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible

If you are using it, attributes that aren't explicitly listed won't get set via `#new`, `#create`, and `#update_attributes` (and a few more).

Comment: This worked! Added -- attr_accessible :name, :regex -- to my iFilter model, and things were good again. Looks like someone upgraded security stuff on our site. : )

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have attribute whitelisting enabled. Make sure you define the attributes that are settable via mass-assignment in your model via the `attr_accessible` macro:

```
class Ifilter
   attr_accessible :name, :regex
   ...
end
```